# Is there any adhoc command in Ansible to run remote commands on remote nodes?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to execute this on the Master Node

```
ansible all -m shell -a "/bin/ping -c3 `hostname`"
```

And instead of pinging remote hostname, it's pinging Master Node

e.g., Master Node hostname = Master

Remote Node hostname = Slave

The above command does this

```
/bin/ping -c3 Master (instead of /bin/ping -c3 Slave)
```

Please suggest on how to achieve this in Ansible.

Answer (score 2):

If you backquote the `hostname` like this: **`hostname`** then it is a command that will be executed on the localhost. If you really want to execute it on remote host, then use `inventory_hostname`

Try:

```
ansible all -m shell -a "/bin/ping -c3 {{inventory_hostname}}"
```

If you want to execute `hostname` in the target host, then escape the `backquote` so that it is not interpreted by the shell on local machine.

```
ansible all -m shell -a "/bin/ping -c3 \`hostname\`"
```

Comment: so there is no way to execute command on remote nodes using backquote \`some_commad\`
Is it possible via Playbook?

Comment: FYI ansible all -m shell -a "/bin/ping -c3 \\`hostname\\`" didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [helloV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4237701/hellov) answer,while `inventory_hostname` is taken from your inventory files, you might also want to look at

- `{{ ansible_nodename }}` -  hostname as the system reports it
- `{{ ansible_hostname }}` -  unqualified hostname that shows the string before the first period(.)

If you really want to use output of `hostname` command instead of ansible gathered facts, you should use single quotes in your command, like

```
ansible all -m shell -a '/bin/ping -c3 `hostname`'
```

Single quotes will preserve exact syntax to be passed to remote hosts, while when you are using double quotes, expression will be evaluated on master node before passed forward to managed hosts

See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) for future reference.

Also, so  please use `$(command)` syntax instead of `` `command` ``, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated

Comment: ansible all -m shell -a '/bin/ping -c3 `hostname` ' is preserving the command as it is.
ping: unknown host  `hostname`

Comment: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html has detailed info on single and double quotes

Comment: Are you sure? What is your target system? On both centos6 and opensuse respectively command

    ansible -i 10.0.8.82,127.0.1 -m shell -a '/bin/ping -c3 $(hostname)'

produced desired result

Comment: with backticks test comand on opensuse and centos 6

ansible -i 10.0.8.82,127.0.1 -m shell -a 'echo `hostname`: `uname -r`'  all
127.0.1 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
linux-4xmi: 4.4.57-18.3-default

10.0.8.82 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
master: 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64

Comment: I'm running the command on centOS 7 and neither the backticks nor the $ one helped here..
"$(hostname)" - taking Master hostname and not remote host name, and

Comment: '$(hostname)' - gives error, saying unknow host $(hostname)